# Добавление страницы в "Мои страницы" на PHP

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, делаю 1 вещь на сайте. В общем, нужно сделать кнопку для добавления страницы в "мои страницы". Например: Человек зашел на страницу page55.html и ему она понравилась, он нажимает на "добавить в мои страницы". После чего на главной странице в соответствующем блоке появляется ссылка на эту страницу. И так можно делать со всеми страницами. Т.е. сколько ссылок будет в блоке не известно. Человек может проделать данную вещь без входа на сайт.

Есть 2 варианта:

1) Создавать куку с IP и добавить в БД 2 столбца IP и link. Далее смотрим, есть ли данный IP (который в куке) в базе. Если да, то выводим инфу с link.

2)Создаем куку и записываем туда каждую добавленную ссылку. Но тогда, как я понял, нужно записывать массив, который будет пополнятся новыми ссылками.

Может есть другие варианты реализации данной функции?

Comment: Если человек зарегистрирован на сайте то в базе просто сохраняете юзер айди и адрес страницы (или любой идентификатор страницы) Если вход не выполнен записывайте просто адреса страницы например в localstorage.

Comment: Кука для каждого пользователя своя. IP можно не писать.